# Continuous-time Markov Chain with absorbing state: How to add a source term?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, singularity

In the situation where you have a continuous-time Markov Chain with rate matrix $M$ and source $\mathbf{b}$ which can be phrased as
$$\partial_t \mathbf{p} = M \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{b},$$
you can normally find a solution for $\mathbf{p}$ via an integrating factor; by multiplying both sides by $e^{Mt}$ and working it out, you can obtain
$$\mathbf{p}(t) = e^{-Mt}\mathbf{p}_0 + e^{-Mt}(I - e^{-Mt})\mathbf{b}.$$
However, in my case, I have a trapping state in $M$. There is one state in my Markov chain from which there is no escape. This state can be reached from two other states; so $M$ can be decomposed into blocks as
$$\begin{bmatrix}M_{11} & \mathbf{m}_{12}\\\mathbf{0} & 1\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\mathbf{m}_{12}$ only has two nonzero elements.
Because of this, NumPy complains that this matrix is singular and therefore cannot be inverted.
Is there a possibility to still solve this Markov Chain effectively?

Thanks for the help already :)

Comment: Unless the determinant of $M_{11}$ is 0, I don't see why this block matrix above should not be invertible.

Comment: How about trying the power iteration method?

Comment: @Gregory it turns out that the determinant of $M_{11}$ is zero, since it is a random walk going 50/50 in either direction. Should I add a small negligible bias to the random walk to assure this is not the case?

Comment: @JacobA why would finding the largest eigenvector of my transition matrix allow me to solve the time evaluation of my Markov chain? I think it might teach me something about the long-term behavior, but I am mostly interested in the short term behavior of the system.

Comment: 1. Your solution for $\mathbf{p}(t)$ doesn't look correct — you should be multiplying by $e^{-Mt}$. 

2. What is the interpretation of the "source" $\bf b$ in Markov chain terms?